# Can't reach Navigator from external imported component class, React states its undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I have an Navigator View which has an initialRoute of 'Login', This loads fine, but it's content comes from external components that I have imported. In one of these, lies a button that tries to call the navigator to change the scene. It reaches it, but states it is undefined.

The error I get is: "this.props.navigator.replace is not a function.(in 'this.props.navigator.replace({id:"splash"}), 'this.porps.navigator.replace' is undefined)"

Not relevant code has been removed

-- 'Navigator' File:

```
export default class Tester extends Component {

render() {
      return (   
          <Navigator
          initialRoute={{id: 'login'}}
          renderScene={(route, nav) => {return this.renderScene(route, nav)}}
          />
      )
}

renderScene(route, nav) {
    switch(route.id) {
      case 'login':
        return <Login navigator={nav} />
      case 'splash':
        return <Splash navigator={nav} />
    }
}
```

-- 'Login' File:

```
export default class Login extends Component {

render() {
      return (
              <View>
                  <LoginForm navigator={navigator} />
              </View>
      );
}

}
```

-- 'LoginForm' File:

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super() 
  navigator = props.navigator;
}

render() {
      return (
          <View>   
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.moveScene.bind(this)} >
                  <Text>LOGIN</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      )
}

moveScene() {
  this.props.navigator.replace({id: "splash"});
}
}
```

Comment: i think you did not declare navigator variable

Comment: Thanks you were right, I just copied the constructor from LoginForm to Login. Add it as an answer if you want